# how to set target to application exe during deployment

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, console-application

I have a console application and I want to deploy/share it using some msi/setup.exe file. I have used Visual Studio Setup Project type. I have created a desktop shortcut in User's desktop folder. But I can not point this shortcut to the application .exe file, it only allow to add application folder.

So what I want, once I install my application (using the msi/exe), it will create a shortcut in desktop, and then when I will click the shortcut it should open the application directly, and not the application folder.

Thanks,
Pritam

Comment: By any chance, is your output (in the deployment project) set to a configuration not just "Default"? I had quite a few weird issues getting VS' deployment to work with that, and the main problem was shortcuts refusing to acknowledge my exe existed. Putting it to Default fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Haven't done this for at least a year.
But if I remember right' Right click on the Project Output and select create shortcut (on the same folder of the output) and then drag and drop it to the desktop folder.

Comment: Thanks..this solve my problem..I found the same solution in this forum http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/431651-create-desktop-shortcut-setup-project

One more question does you know how to open the application exe as administrator by default. My application will not run untill and unless the exe open as a admin.

Comment: Modify your application's manifest, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx - you can tell it to always ask for elevated credentials. The last time I dealt with this it was even in the manifest by default, just commented out.